# Why pyautogui can't find the second image after finding the first one?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui, time



try:
    position2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("C:/Users/NS/Desktop/roll.png", confidence=0.8)
    x = position2[0]
    y = position2[1]
    print(x,y)
    print('Found! Clicking above the image')

    pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(button='left')
    time.sleep(1)
except:
    pass
    print("Fail! Didn't find the image")

time.sleep(10)
try:
    position2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("C:/Users/NS/Desktop/sing.png", confidence=0.8)
    x = position2[0]
    y = position2[1]
    print(x,y)
    print('Found! Clicking above the image')

    pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(button='left')
    time.sleep(1)
except:
    pass
    print("Fail! Didn't find the image")
```

The code runs properly for the first part but it just can't find the second image. If I remove the first part, it is able find the second image but not when both the codes are written one after other. Why is it happening?